# How should I represent/store a song duration as a property? I want to use a common song duration format such as "HH:MM:SS"

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, model, nsdate

I have a custom class called Song. Each instance of this class needs to have a property which represents its duration, and I want that duration in a normal "songy" format like HH:MM:SS. The Song instances will be receiving data, such as duration, from JSON network calls, and they also might be persisted via Core Data or some other method.

What are my options to store this duration? Do I need to store it has a string like

```
self.duration = @"0:2:14";
```

or

```
 self.duration = @"0.2.14";
```

Would storing it as a NSNumber of NSDate be better? If so, how do I convert it to those types? If I need to store it as a string, is there a better way to convert it into a number/time interval than splitting the colons?

Comment: Neither `NSNumber` or `NSDate`, both have some specific properties behaviours.

In your case you need only to store value to show it as `05hours:23minutes:04seconds` i.e., `05:23:04`

These are fixed value, and you require it as string, so store them as string. Also storing it as string  doesn't matter how you use, any one will be fine.

Comment: Store it as an integer representing the number of seconds. That would provide the flexibility of changing the format easily if requirements change.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya What do you mean by `specific properties behaviours`?

Comment: NSNumber with two decimals (2.4.5) or (d:f:e) i guess look awkward, and nsdate stores timeinterval from gmt 1jan1970. so all your songs needs to be based on 1970. do you really need that/

Answer (score 1):

You should store the duration in seconds (or milliseconds if you want to be that exact) as an integer. Then convert that to a pretty format when displaying the time, for example through a method `-(NSString*)displayDuration`

If you declare your duration property like this

```
@property (nonatomic) int duration;
```

then you could write a method to get an `NSString` for display:

```
- (NSString*)displayDuration {
    int remainingDuration = self.duration;
    int seconds = remainingDuration%60;
    remainingDuration/=60;
    int minutes = remainingDuration%60;
    remainingDuration/=60;
    int hours = remainingDuration;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way to do that with `NSDateFormatter` or something like it?

Comment: +1 for the general idea of storing as time interval and converting to "pretty format", but I would use double (same as NSTimeInterval) type, not integer, and I would consider using NSDateFormatter to create pretty strings. For HH:MM:SS only your suggestion works though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDateComponent`

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()            
let comps = cal.components([.Day, .Hour, .Minute], fromDate: self, toDate: otherDate, options: [])
return (comps.day , comps.hour , comps.minute)
```

where self is a `NSDate` and otherDate is also a `NSDate` (this was implemented as an extension to `NSDate`)

Add components as you like (here are only days, hour, minutes)

The example code returns a tuple. Accessible via `.0`, `.1`, `.2` allowing string formatting in whatever way necessary.

Code is in Swift 2